# getCheckedItemCount() returns wrong value after cursor change

Tags: android, android-listview

What I'm trying to do is to put `ListView` in my app which uses internal SQLite database to get data. When user clicks new data is fetched from DB by executing new query.

I've implemented custom view for `ListView` item which extends `LinearLayout` and implements `Checkable` interface. Works.

Got custom adapter based on `CursorAdapter`. In `OnCreate()` I'm setting my adapter for `ListView` with empty cursor.

```
ListView markersList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.markersList);

Cursor c = null;
MarkersListAdapter adapter = new MarkersListAdapter(this, c, 0);
markersList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Next in `AsyncTask` I'm querying database in `doInBackground()` which passes new cursor to `onPostExecute()` to update `ListView`. I'm doing this with:

```
adapter.changeCursor(newCursor);
```

Then I'm by default checking all items (user just uncheck unwanted items)

```
for(int i = 0; i < this.markersList.getCount(); i++)
{        
    this.markersList.setItemChecked(i, true);
}
```

So far so good. But when I do

```
int s = this.markersList.getCheckedItemCount();
```

I'm getting wrong value. I guess it's associated with old cursor. This only happens when rows count in new cursor is smaller than rows count in new cursor.

Generally, I'm getting something like this

```
int s = this.markersList.getCheckedItemCount();   // s = 7
int d = this.markersList.getCount();              // d = 5
```

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to clear the checked count manually:

```
this.markersList.clearChoices();
for(int i = 0; i < this.markersList.getCount(); i++)
{        
    this.markersList.setItemChecked(i, true);
}
```